# How move MSBuild parameters to the project file

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, tfs, msbuild

I'm new to MSBuild, and all the tutorials I found are quite not for the beginners. I have a build task on TFS that uses the following MSBuild parameters:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=InProc /p:DeployIisAppPath="ABC" /p:MsDeployServiceUrl="http://webserver" /p:UserName="ABC\CBA" /p:Password="abcPwd"
```

Now as I have other requirements I would like to move these parameters to the project file, but I have no idea where to start or how to do it.

Any indication or link on a good tutorial is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So are you saying that you always want these values for your parameters? If so, then just create a Property Group with those properties in your project file. It would look like this in your project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DeployOnBuild>true</DeployOnBuild>
    <DeployTarget>MsDeployPublish</DeployTarget>
    <CreatePackageOnPublish>true</CreatePackageOnPublish>   
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>InProc</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <DeployIisAppPath>ABC</DeployIisAppPath>
    <MsDeployServiceUrl>http://webserver</MsDeployServiceUrl>
    <UserName>ABC\CBA</UserName>
    <Password>abcPwd</Password>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I think this is what you're looking for. If my understanding of your needs isn't quite right, let me know and I'll see what I can do to help out.